# Parse value defined macro in C header file using Java CDT parser

Tags: java, c, eclipse-cdt

For example, I have a header.h file which has a few value defined macro:

```
#define MACRO1 value1
#define MACRO2 value2
```

I would like to parse these macros using Java CDT parser and store its name as well as the value and store it into a map and print them:

```
MACRO1 = value1
MACRO2 = value2
```

I have researched on some source but all of them just showing how to parser the macro name only.

And my expectation would be loop through a map and print them.

For example:

```
MACRO1 = value1
MACRO2 = value2
```

Answer (score 0):

you should build your `translationUnit` first, and then use `translationUnit.getMacroDefinitions()` to get all your macros, after that you can use `macroDefinition.getName()` as the `key`, use `macroDefinition.getRawSignature()` as the value.